# PHP mysqli select by group and random

Tags: php, mysqli

Not sure if this is possible. I am trying to get a mysqli query to work that will group results together and then inside each group display the results randomly. Here is my current code which just produces all the results in random order.

```
select * from swt_counties_members 
where 
  county_id=".$sCounty[1]." 
AND 
  status=1 
OR 
  county_id=0 
AND 
  status=1 
order by rand()
```

What i need it to do is group by service_id and then display random for the records in each group. Something like this

```
select * from swt_counties_members 
where 
  county_id=".$sCounty[1]." 
AND 
  status=1 
OR 
  county_id=0 
AND 
  status=1 
group by service_id 
order by rand()
```

where it will group all results first by service_id and then display the results in each of the group randomly

Hope that makes sense :)
Many thanks

Comment: `Group by` is not for showing each record in a group. Its for grouping in order to aggregate, like `sum()` or `avg()`.

Comment: Thats a pain then. Used to be able to do that (old school) Is there a different way I can achieve this?

Comment: @developerwjk Ok I can select them using order by service_id but is there a way I can use random for each ordered result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want ORDER BY, not GROUP BY

```
select * from swt_counties_members where county_id=".$sCounty[1]." AND status=1 OR county_id=0 AND status=1 order by service_id,rand()
```

Comment: I tried that earlier and got this error Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given.... I just noticed on your example there is a comma after service_id which i have now used and it is working.   Many thanks :)